# Error 404 despite that page exists Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have something like `website.com/profile/nameofuser` that is working.
But if I have `website.com/profile/_nameofuser` I get `404 error` also `website.com/profile/nameofuser_` or `website.com/profile/nameof_user` is working. It's not something related to accepted characters, but what's the problem?

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() 
{       
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->load->model('Profile_model');  
    $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form', 'htmlpurifier'));
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    if(getUserData($this->uri->segment(2), "ID") < 0) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Profil inexistent.');
        redirect(base_url());
    }

    if (!is_cache_valid(md5('profile' . $this->uri->segment(2) . ''), 300)){
            $this->db->cache_delete('profile', $this->uri->segment(2));
        }

    if(getUserData($this->uri->segment(2), "ID") > 0) {

        /* some mysql queries.. */
        }

        $data["main_content"] = 'profile/profile_view';
        $this->load->view('includes/template.php', $data); 
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Profil inexistent.');
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
function _remap($method,$args)
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method))
    {
        $this->$method($args);  
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index($method,$args);
    }
}
}
```

Here is my profile controller. I really don't know what's the problem. If I enter an invalid profile redirects with error flashdata so ti's ok. Maybe it's a remap problem?

Comment: you should make your example more clear, `website.com/profile/nameofuser` and `website.com/profile/nameofuser` sounds the same to me, how could it work and also it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show some code from your `profile` controller? This seems like either you're trying to access a method that doesn't exist or you're trying to load a view that doesn't exist... Showing the declaration for your `nameofuser` method and the views you're calling within that method may help pinpoint the issue

Comment: @JavierLarroulet added profile controller.

Comment: @HastaDhana added profile controller.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check the fie format in your view file.. if it is html file that mean you cannot call it without its format
for example 
if your file is php format have name home-view.php
you can call it as

```
$this->load->view('home-view');
```

but if it is html file then the name in home-view.html
so you have to call it with its exstention as

```
$this->load->view('home-view.html');
```

Comment: Let me explain, if i have 3 users like:
first_username - exist in db, shows the profile, everything is ok,
second_username - not exist in db, redirect with error flashdata
and _thirdusername - exist in db, redirect 404

Comment: i cannot explain it without looking at controller... and if you have created an library to control users... i need to look at library too...

Comment: it seems like you are new at codeigniter.. are you??

Comment: Yes, i'm new. I posted the controller in the first post.

Comment: masih.ansari2@gmail.com.. contact me if you ever want to know.. join me on hangout

Answer (score 0):

your call to `/profile/nameofuser` is missing a fundamental from the MVC architecture.

You need to call a controller/method combination (in CI, your basic url is domain.com/controller/method)...

since you don't have a specific method for each user within the profile controller, which is actually a good thing, you need a method within the controller that handles your users. You already have it, it's called `index`

If you point your URL to `/profile/index/nameofuser` and change `$this->uri->segment(2)` to `$this->uri->segment(3)` you should get it to work

give it a try and let me know

Comment: I don't get it, because /profile/simpleuser is work and redirect me to the profile, only if i put _ in front of is not working and redirects me to 404 page.

Comment: I stand corrected.. I hadn't noticed your _remap() method (which redirects to index if your URL doesn't contain a valid method name) ... however, I'm not getting why would you append an underscore to `nameofuser`considering you expect it to be a number (you are checking with a `>` or `<` comparison operator, which leads me to think that in that case you're falling onto your `else` statement and there's something wrong with your redirect... CI's redirect expects a CI route as argument, but base_url is not that but the url to your main CI index (not the same)

Comment: And how can I repair this?

Comment: Well it depends... Do you really expect `nameofuser` to always be a number? If so, there would be nothing in need of fixing since numbers don't contain underscores. If `nameofuser` can be any string, you need to rethink the validation you're performing and not use greater than or smaller than comparison operators

Comment: getUserData($this->uri->segment(2), "ID") returns name of the user based on that ID in mysql, for example for id 33 in DB is the name TestUser. The problem is that if I start the name underline i don't why redirect 404 not found even that user exist, but if i enter an user that isn't exist I get error flashdata so that is ok.

Comment: Like I said, since you are expecting segment 2 to be the I'd from the table, if the ID will always be numeric, appending an underscore will make the `if` clause fail (a number with an underscore is no longer a number, thus checking whether it is greater than 0 will fail)